# Why does second terminal tab prompt bundle install

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ruby-on-rails

If I run `rails s` in the terminal, it works. If I open a new terminal window or tab and run

`rails c`

I get the following error:

> Run bundle install to install missing gems.

If I run `cd ..` and then cd back into the directory, and I have to run `rails c` again, it works. My question is what would be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing some problems but didn't find the perfect solution.

But you use the following thing to avoid your repetitive task of changing directory then use rails c, sidekiq rails command.

open your `.bash_profile` file using the following commands.

```
cd ~ 
nano .bash_profile
```

Then add the following code at the end of your bash_profile file

```
current_dir=$(pwd)
cd $current_dir
```